# Product delete et re-create

Tags: magento2, product, configurable-product, delete

I am curious to know. In Magento2,

if a product has been ordered, then deleted, then it has been re-created with the same SKU, will it be considered as one and the same product, or a diifferent one?

Please, also answer for Configurable products with virtual variations.

Thanks!

Comment: Nope for confiurable product. because configurable product store simple products by thier entity id not sku.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Magento definitely consider a new product because in database foreign key relation is based on product `entity_id` and same as apply to configurable product. In below Image you can see that `catalog_product_super_link` (Where magento saves relation between parent and child) has relation with only product id nothing else. So If you remove the product and recreate then new product has different Id.

[image]